# What is the issue about dynamically create and add foreignGroup to svg

Tags: javascript, dynamic, svg

I have problem when I'm dynamically creating **foreignGroup** with form input elements using javascript. I can see elements on browser inspector, but it doesn't come visible somehow. It suppose to visible!!

**javascript:**

```
    var forObj = document.createElement("foreignObject");
        forObj.setAttribute("x", "100");
        forObj.setAttribute("y", "100");
        forObj.setAttribute("width", "200");
        forObj.setAttribute("height", "250");
        forObj.setAttribute("background", "red");


    var askInput = document.createElement("input");
        askInput.setAttribute("id", "test");
        askInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
        askInput.setAttribute("width", "300");
        askInput.setAttribute("height", "50");
        askInput.setAttribute("x", "100");
        askInput.setAttribute("y", "100");

        forObj.appendChild(askInput);

        mySvg.appendChild(forObj);
```

If i add **foreignGroup** in svg straight to php file, it works and there is not any issue.

Is this bug or what, or what I'm missing.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you may need [`document.createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElementNS).

Comment: Post your ultimate code as a solution, which at a later point you can select as the correct answer.

Comment: I can't answer for my own guestion yet, because my reputation needs to be more than 10. I can post WORKING FUNCTION solution after I get reputation better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy, like first comment says, **use document.createElementNS** instead of **document.createElement**, like this:

```
var forObj = document.createElementNS("foreignObject");
        forObj.setAttribute("x", "100");
        forObj.setAttribute("y", "100");
        forObj.setAttribute("width", "200");
        forObj.setAttribute("height", "250");
        forObj.setAttribute("background", "red");


    var askInput = document.createElementNS("input");
        askInput.setAttribute("id", "test");
        askInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
        askInput.setAttribute("width", "300");
        askInput.setAttribute("height", "50");
        askInput.setAttribute("x", "100");
        askInput.setAttribute("y", "100");

        forObj.appendChild(askInput);

        mySvg.appendChild(forObj);
```